# Postgres Crosstab query - "duplicate category" error where 2 values have the first 62 characters in common

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-sql, crosstab

I'm a newbie working on a postgres 9.5 (dynamic) crosstab query, that has been working fine in general, but I've come up with a peculiar issue with large nearly identical category names and I hope there's an easy solution/explanation.

Requires tablefunc:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS tablefunc;
```

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_table (id integer, name text, data text);
INSERT INTO temp_table VALUES (1, 'ThisSentenceIsExactlySixtyTwoCharactersLongPlusNumbersAtTheEnd',  'data1');
INSERT INTO temp_table VALUES (2, 'ThisSentenceIsExactlySixtyTwoCharactersLongPlusNumbersAtTheEnd1',  'data2');
```

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM CROSSTAB($$SELECT id, name, data FROM temp_table ORDER BY 1,2$$ , $$SELECT DISTINCT name FROM temp_table$$) AS ct (row integer, col_1 text,col_2 text);
```

Instead of the result I expect, I get:

> ERROR: duplicate category name SQL state: 42710

Can anyone please tell me what's going on here, and if there's a simple fix? 
Thanks!

Comment: As a workaround, in my actual program that generates the temp_table I've added an id number prefix to the name field to keep them all distinct within the first 62 characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact that PostgreSQL truncates identifiers (including column names and category names) to 63 characters. Seems like there's an off-by-one error somewhere in crosstab as well maybe. Do your names need to be so long? That's probably the easiest fix. You could also try increasing NAMEDATALEN and recompiling postgres.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it looks like it has to do with the identifier truncating. In most cases I don't think this would matter, but as I was creating a crosstab based on user provided data, I ran into this issue with some rather long names that were only distinguishable at the end of the string.